# Passing parameter in Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up Jenkins job and I need to make it parametrized such that it can take below parameters and pass it to my build script.

Parameters - 
Entry point: E1/E2 (default : E1)
Protocols: ABC, DEF, … (default : all)

Build script :

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}/myworkSpace 
 mvn clean install -P **E1** -Dformat.type=**ABC**    

 mvn clean install -P **E2** -Dformat.type=**DEF**
```

I tried with $Parameter but it dint work for me. Please suggest what is correct approach to do this parametrization.

Comment: `I tried with $Parameter` does it means you jenkins job is already parameterized and `Parameter` is the name?

Comment: Yes. I created parametrized job with Entry point and Protocols parameters and I can select E1,E2 or ABC, DEF from UI. I am not sure how can I pass this parameter to my script "mvn clean install -P E1 -Dformat.type=ABC" when I select it from Jenkins build UI.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I understand that you have defined two parameters from the UI, and you were able to add a default value.

```
entry_point=E1
format=ABC
```

In your build's UI, you have a "Execute Shell" section, to re-use these parameters:

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}/myworkSpace
mvn clean install -P $entry_point -Dformat.type=$format
```

When executed with the default commands, it will produce the following command:

```
mvn clean install -P E1 -Dformat.type=ABC
```

Your variable name does not need to be in uppercase. But the name should be identical.

If you need more details about the fancy usage of this awesome plugin, you can have a look there:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build